# In vim, how do you run a command silently in the background?

Tags: vim, vi, editors

I'm using Ubuntu and currently have the following line in my vimrc file:

```
nnoremap < leader >dc :execute 'silent !drush cc all' | redraw!
```

The command works but it doesn't hit me back to the editor. It waits to finish running the command first. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 7):

As the external command is executed through the shell, you just have to append a `&` to launch the process in the background:

```
nnoremap <leader>dc :execute 'silent !drush cc all &' | redraw!
```

Comment: why is the redraw needed?

Comment: @divramod Explanation is at the end of [`:help :!cmd`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3A%21cmd).